# Replace string with htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to replace a string in URL with htaccess RewriteRule. The idea is to catch every request beginning with `prodotti`, replace it with `products` and leave the rest the same. For example

1. `prodotti/category/id.html` becomes `products/category/id.html`
2. `prodotti/category.html` becomes `products/category.html`
3. `prodotti.html` becomes `products.html`

I've tried the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^prodotti products [QSA,NC]
```

(I'm omitting the `L` flag because after this replacement I need to make further RewriteRules).

The rule works fine for everything but the replacement #3 (it doesn't match). How can I change it to match all replacements with a single `RewriteRule` line?

**EDIT**

Here's the list of further RewriteRules I need to perform after the replacement.

```
# products/category/id.html
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ mvc.php?rt=products/index&category=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# products/category.html
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)\.html$ mvc.php?rt=products/index&category=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Did you try `RewriteRule prodotti\w*(.*?)(prodotti(\w*))?(\..*) products$1products$3$4 [QSA,NC]`? It will handle URLs with 2 'prodotti' in them. `http://example.com/prodotti/prodottiID.html` --> `http://example.com/products/productsID.html`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^prodotti(.*)$ products$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see my edit, I've added the further RewriteRules I need to perform after the replacement. Unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to work for the  `prodotti/categoryID.html` rule (I expected to get `category=categoryID` but I get `category=categoryID.html`). A similar consideration may be made for the `prodotti/categoryID/productID.html` URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RewriteRule ^prodotti\.html$ /products.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct but I would like to match all with a single `RewriteRule`. Thanks anyway for the answer.